# UISwitch saving values to use in a function

Tags: swift, uiswitch

When the user turns switch on, I would like a random value to display on a UILabel, then take that same random value, and use it to multiply and find another value. I think my problem is that I am trying to use a let statement to hold the value, then trying to call back to that let value from another function, but I don't know another way to to this.

I already can get the random value to appear on a UILabel after the switch is active. Then when the switch is not active, a value of 0 is left on the UILabel.

The IBOutlet for the switch:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tipSwitch: UISwitch!
```

This is the action for the switch:

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn{
        sender.setOn(false, animated: true)
        percentPlaceholder.text! = String(0) + "%"


    }
    else{
        sender.setOn(true, animated: true)
        let randomTip = Int.random(in: 1...100)
        percentPlaceholder.text! = String(randomTip)
        calculateTipSwitch()
    }

}
```

This is the calculateTipSwitch function:

```
func calculateTipSwitch() {
    var tipAmountSwitch = Float()
    var totalCostSwitch = Float()
    if let billAmountSwitch = Float(billCost.text!) {
        tipAmountSwitch = billAmountSwitch * randomTip / 100
        totalCostSwitch = tipAmountSwitch + billAmountSwitch
    }
    else {
        tipAmountSwitch = 0
        totalCostSwitch = 0
    }
    tipDollarAmt.text! = String(format: "%.2f", tipAmountSwitch)
    totalBill.text! = String(format: "%.2f", totalCostSwitch)
}
```

Here is all of my code if you want a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var billCost: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var percentPlaceholder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipDollarAmt: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalBill: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipSegment: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipSwitch: UISwitch!
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowed = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".1234567890")
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowed) != nil
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    billCost.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    percentPlaceholder.text = ""
    tipDollarAmt.text = ""
    totalBill.text = ""
}
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    percentPlaceholder.text! = String(Int(sender.value)) + "%"
    tipStepper.value = Double(Int(tipSlider.value))
    calculateTip()
}
@IBAction func selectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

}
@IBAction func stepperChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    percentPlaceholder.text! = String(sender.value) + "%"
    tipSlider.value = Float(tipStepper.value)
    calculateTipStep()
}
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn{
        sender.setOn(false, animated: true)
        percentPlaceholder.text! = String(0) + "%"


    }
    else{
        sender.setOn(true, animated: true)
        let randomTip = Int.random(in: 1...100)
        percentPlaceholder.text! = String(randomTip)

    }

}

func calculateTip()
{
    var tipAmount = Float()
    var totalCost = Float()
    if let billAmount = Float(billCost.text!) {
        tipAmount = billAmount * tipSlider.value / 100
        totalCost = tipAmount + billAmount
    }
    else {
        tipAmount = 0
        totalCost = 0
    }
    tipDollarAmt.text! = String(format: "%.2f", tipAmount)
    totalBill.text! = String(format: "%.2f", totalCost)
}
func calculateTipStep() {
    var tipAmountStep = Float()
    var totalCostStep = Float()
    if let billAmountStep = Float(billCost.text!) {
        tipAmountStep = billAmountStep * Float(tipStepper.value) / 100
        totalCostStep = tipAmountStep + billAmountStep
    }
    else {
        tipAmountStep = 0
        totalCostStep = 0
    }
    tipDollarAmt.text! = String(format: "%.2f", tipAmountStep)
    totalBill.text! = String(format: "%.2f", totalCostStep)
}
func calculateTipSwitch() {
    var tipAmountSwitch = Float()
    var totalCostSwitch = Float()
    if let billAmountSwitch = Float(billCost.text!) {
        tipAmountSwitch = billAmountSwitch * randomTip / 100
        totalCostSwitch = tipAmountSwitch + billAmountSwitch
    }
    else {
        tipAmountSwitch = 0
        totalCostSwitch = 0
    }
    tipDollarAmt.text! = String(format: "%.2f", tipAmountSwitch)
    totalBill.text! = String(format: "%.2f", totalCostSwitch)
}
}
```

Basically my problem is that I can't use that random number in another function, so I just need help on how to call back to that randomTip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter to `calculateTipSwitch`, and pass the random number as an argument to the `calculateTipSwitch` method. Change `calculateTipSwitch` to:

```
func calculateTipSwitch(tipPercentage: Int) {
    var tipAmountSwitch = Float()
    var totalCostSwitch = Float()
    if let billAmountSwitch = Float(billCost.text!) {
        tipAmountSwitch = billAmountSwitch * tipPercentage / 100.0
        totalCostSwitch = tipAmountSwitch + billAmountSwitch
    }
    else {
        tipAmountSwitch = 0
        totalCostSwitch = 0
    }
    tipDollarAmt.text! = String(format: "%.2f", tipAmountSwitch)
    totalBill.text! = String(format: "%.2f", totalCostSwitch)
}
```

Then, in `switchChanged`:

```
let randomTip = Int.random(in: 1...100)
percentPlaceholder.text! = String(randomTip)
calculateTipSwitch(tipPercentage: randomTip)
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me. It still isn't recognizing the randomTip amount. Would you happen to know any other fixes? "Use of unresolved identifier 'randomTip'; did you mean 'srandomdev'? Replace 'randomTip' with 'srandomdev'" this is the error I was getting. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jon Oops, seems like I've made a copy-paste error. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep, that works! I also had to change the tipPercentage to Float(tipPercentage), but besides that, your method worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the switchChanged() function , you set the randomTip to percentPlaceholder.text , so in the other functions , you could just call for it.

```
let randomTip = percentPlaceholder.text
```

Or another way to do this, is to declare the randomTip variable outside the function, as a property of the class.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    //IBOutlets here 

    var randomTip : String?

    //functions here
}
```

Then when you set a value to it in switchChanged(), it can be called in the other functions.

Comment: I tried your method, and got this error, "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'String' ". Would you know a way to fix this?

Comment: // In the calculateTipSwitch()      if let billAmountSwitch = Float(billCost.text!) , let randomTip = Float(randomTip)  {   tipAmountSwitch = billAmountSwitch * tipPercentage / 100.0        totalCostSwitch = tipAmountSwitch + billAmountSwitch }